# Solving of the first-order nonlinear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Good day. Can you give me advice about solution of the equation $(x+1)(y'+y^2)=-y$? I guess it is Riccati's equation.

Answer (score 4):

Dividing by $y^2$, we get
$$(x+1)\left[-\left(\frac1y\right)'+1\right]=-\frac1y,$$
or, in terms of $u=1/y$:
$$(x+1)(u'-1)=u\qquad \Longrightarrow\qquad u'-\frac{u}{x+1}=1.$$
Further, introducing $u=(x+1)v$, this linear differential equation transforms into
$$v'=\frac{1}{x+1}.$$
I believe you can take it from here.

Comment: Thank you! You really helped me!

Comment: Hi Ben, if you like this answer, please click the tick next to it to accept it as the answer and signify that it has been solved.

Comment: @Ben You are welcome!